# Echo PHP code inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am having problem getting this to work. I am trying to echo some php code to html if the page is in an iframe. Below is a short example of the php code i try to echo (the real code i try to echo is much longer)...

```
<?php $pic='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/17/58/sample-815141_960_720.jpg'; ?>

<div id="frameid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function inIframe () {
        try {
            return window.self !== window.top;
        } catch (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (inIframe()) {
        var node = document.getElementById('frameid');
        node.innerHTML('<?php echo '<img width="100%" src="'.$pic.'"></img>'; ?>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: no output to html, only as text in javascipt tag

Comment: Would you send entire code?

Comment: If you want to write `php` in `JavaScript` you have to need add [Handlebar](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template engine, where you can write php or direct html by following `{{{ }}}` curly braces and reguler expression declared by `{{}}` curly brace

Comment: This is a really bad idea, `echo some php code to html` the security implications of this are .. well .. horrible.  Even if it was possible, I would advise you not to do it.

Comment: @Momin No, that's completely incorrect. Handlebars is not a PHP interpreter. It cannot run PHP code.

Comment: @duskwuff But if i write it on three curly braces default language will be interpret by its own server !

Comment: I have edited the above sample code with a simple example of the php i try to echo, the actual one is more complex, but above does not work as well

Comment: @Momin No, it won't. That isn't how Javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was some quotes issue. You can try the below code:

```
<div id="frameid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function inIframe () {
        try {
            return window.self !== window.top;
        } catch (e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (inIframe()) {
        var node = document.getElementById('frameid');
        node.innerHTML(<?php echo "...something involving html and php variables...."; ?>);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
var pic = ;
innerHTML("");
I think is more clear to separate js from php, and recomanded

Answer (score -1):

You are having troubles with single quote, you may consider this function (taken from WP https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_specialchars/) to escape quote (single and double)

`node.innerHTML('<?php echo esc_attr('<img width="100%" src="'.$pic.'"></img>'); ?>');`

where you can define

```
function esc_attr( $text ) {
    return _wp_specialchars( $safe_text, ENT_QUOTES );
}
```

Comment: used your code and div#frameid is still empty, and now the javascript stopped at node.innerHTML('